# How to check if all list elements are different in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a `List[(Int, Int)]` and I would like to check if all the elements in my list are **different**.

How can I achieve this in Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scala> val xs = List((1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2))
xs: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (1,3), (1,2))

scala> xs.distinct.lengthCompare(xs) == 0
res0: Boolean = false
```

P.S. But use `HashMap`/`HashSet` from Scala  collections wisely to avoid security vulnerabilities on untrusted input under DoS/DoW attacks that exploit [hash collision vulnerabilities](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/hash-collision-vulnerability-in-default-hashmap-and-hashset-implementations/3740) of them directly or indirectly through Scala collections methods that use them under hood: `toMap`, `keys`, `distinct`, `groupBy`, etc..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your code gives me the following error: `type missmatch, expected: Int, actual: List[(Int, Int)]`. Iam using IntelliJ

Comment: should it be `xs.length`?

Comment: Which Scala version do you use?

Comment: Iam using version `2.12.7`

Comment: Yeap, for 2.12.x it should be `xs.distinct.lengthCompare(xs.length)`